# How to change style of the first line in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to change style of the first line in UITextView as this is done in the Notes app from Apple. Their first line has bigger bold font. How this can be implemented?

And I want other lines change style their style dynamically as it's on Apple Notes iOS default app. When I create new note, style of first line is big bold. But when I start type another line style dynamically change to the simple.

Comment: Text view will accept an attributed string.  This is a string that contains style information (attributes) particular to substrings or to the whole thing. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring?language=objc).

Answer (score 1):

As @danh commented, you can use the attributed text quality of the UITextView to do this. Simply set the text type to "Attributed" in the interface editor, and then use the following code to set your text. This code uses html, though there are various different ways to create Attributed Text.

[image: Interface Editor]

Code:

```
    let html = """
    <p><strong><span style="font-size: 48px;">First Line</span></strong></p>
    <p><span style="font-size: 28px;">Other Lines</span></p>
    <p><span style="font-size: 28px;">Other Lines</span></p>
    <p><span style="font-size: 28px;">Other Lines</span></p>
    """

    let data = Data(html.utf8)

    if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {

        textView.attributedText = attributedString

    }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I tried your code, but for me all lines are the same font. Don't know what the problem and how this can be fixed.

Comment: Try downloading and testing these: https://github.com/kps2501/Misc

Comment: Thank you for example, but I want first line change style dynamically when creating new notes, as it's on Apple Notes iOS default app. When I create new note, style of first line is big bold. But when I start type another line style dynamically change to the simple.

Comment: You could set the initial text style to be bold, and change it to be regular text after return is pressed, or check to see which line is currently selected to do the same. As I said in my answer, you don’t have to use html to create attributed strings, there are other ways to create them.

Comment: it to be regular text after return is pressed, or check to see which line is currently selected to do the same - and how this can be done? Can you suggest? I looked at delegates UITextView, but didn't found this functions.

Comment: @alexsmith textDidChange? Search StackOverFlow for more on this, there’s many answers available.